# Push a view from a custom table view cell Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, load, tableview, cell

I was wondering if there was a way to have the user create/delete cells in a Table View but when they click on it, every cell that they create loads the same view. I have the first part created but I cannot seem to get it to load a view.

Answer (score 1):

Simple create a new view and push on didSelectRowAtIndexPath Delegate method of UITableView.

For ex.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
    DetailViewController *vController = [[DetailViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vController animated:YES];
    [vController release];
}
```